# Distribute a Generic Function Over a Tuple

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

Im trying to write a more strictly typed version of `Array<T>.map` which preserves tuple lengths and narrowed types.

I've tried doing so by first implementing a function that maps a tuple of `string` to a tuple of `string` of the sorts of `mapTuple(tuple, func)` where `tuple` is a tuple of `string` and `func` is a function that maps a specific element in `tuple` to another specific string.

Consider the following inputs for mapTuple:

```js
["a", "b", "c"] // tuple
e => `__${e}` // func
```

I want the resulting type to be:

```js
["__a", "__b", "__c"]
```

To phrase it differently I want to distribute the generic function `func`, which could have a type of `` <T extends string> (e:T) => `__${e}` as const `` over a tuple, which could have a type of `["a", "b", "c"]`

From what I know by know, higher order generics could solve this easily, which are unfortunately not available in TS yet.

What I've tried so far: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSxQBwFcMAuAbQCIpyAaecgIxrrHIF0BuAWACgeB6PhgAW2NPFQJgSEGhRYUsGEgDu8KcpTwMSLUIS5CGMSBRICAcyHEeoSLAQAzAijAZsqeAFsoeACoE8CBAAHh54eH88eBAADwwTYDFMGFxzeFJWajD4ADFnMGi4hLFggFFC+JREiIDSAGsQAE8kBxq8VgA+AAoQYnhSgEp4AF4O+GTUnm6MAKC+yNonFz68lwG+gG9s0gBpHE0G5tbI1j6MRrwQFvglsGDI3c6eAF8eHmR0LFuR+HuK4vgXXOl2uBiIA3qTWuwKurTBGE6XQAblAIARehEhqN4AADAD6eIAJBsUWiQM8cfAoGIPph3qhMOMMClXABZHyXYCRII-bx+WYgLrwxb5AZcbjhSXhATpHp9SjkLFjCYocy0OV0RhKpkpVXqjHkFjalXmVjZKXwGVoJCeEBCFQ3fL3Wo7To4MS4BwgGBwYBUsQ4gB0wexJspuEwICgfuuQZDY3IBKoONoSGE3uUogQACUQDMYCgAGqo9HBW7OvCPDpjZRmCB++gIZRCKBYACS8BQIBAwDevG4AmEonEXfgtZgdTE9CIamksiwnu9ugQcHzmhh4la3ygVXgBDQMhwWFigWwYGwGAgjRs4GgcEdLjcHj53JAACZQhK2v8qklmal0kybJVgKWJKmqMof2qB5DmuE5ugxQYRmVf9VSmIEBXmAIRWWXJRU2bY9lweBYOOAJTlxAliQeV0KRePtaSwCY2Q5HtXzfXkfHYoV8CIHCwDFc0LUtPgKCTJhEzxRhaEklgzS-YSRPgcw8w9FAvR9HtECQTTXCvWhp3kbtqm0PcDypTRsE8U9zywPk8AAiN4mjTd9g03U0nTeBVwIAt4FJdFXNuPseCAA)

I can't seem to get the mapped type narrowed down to the return type of the function when invoked with the mapping variable. Also everything I've tried using `infer` also widened to `string` as the result: `typeof func<Tup[K]> extends (a:any) => infer A ? A : never`

Is there any way to archive this using current TypeScript?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAd5ZN) works for you

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine It is my understanding that they wish to avoid the use of the explicit mapping in the return type because that is redundant and not reusable.

Comment: @vera. don't know. The closest approach is [this](https://tsplay.dev/m33jkm). Also, higher order types are not supported in TS, hence not sure what OP wants exactly

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine unfortunately not, thats similar to what I already had, as vera pointed out, I want to have a generalizable, generic mapTuple function similar to Array.map, that infers the return type based on the function given

Comment: @dsalex1 see [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzYJm)

Comment: The closest you can probably get to is using some sort of HKT (higher-kinded type) mimicry, which I can demonstrate [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOxOpN) using geoffrey's `free-types` library.

Comment: @vera. I believe this is the edge of TS posibilities in terms of HKT